# Import AngelSensor angel-sdk in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import the sdk `angel-sdk` in Android Studio 1.5.1 to develop an android-app. I downloaded the zip-file from github (https://github.com/AngelSensor/angel-sdk). The sdk is in the zip-file and is called `angel-sdk`.

I created a new Project, select minimum Android SDK 19 and created a blank activity. Now I was trying the `angel-sdk` via `new->import Module`. After this I activated the Dependencies in `Project Structure ->Dependencies` and selected `:angel-sdk`. But then I got an error:

[image]

I don't know what I have to do that the Project is free of errors.

Answer (score 0):

i recently started to work with the angel sdk, here's how i did it.

Open project structure (F4) and add a new module, when asked, select .arr library and look inside the sample-app folder, the only lib needed is the debug one, so find the *angel-sdk-debug* fodler and select the angel-sdk-debug.aar file.

After adding the new module, you have to add it as dependecy, to do that, go again to de project structure, select the `app module` and then the dependencies tab.

Finally, under the Gradle scripts you'll find the build.gradle for the module `angel-sdk-debug`, open it and change the line `configurations.maybeCreate("default")` to `configurations.create("default")`

after that everything should work just fine!